# Cannot assign negative value

Tags: php, mysql

`UPDATE posts set votes=votes+1 where id='$id'`

The above works when the value is zero, but when i Subtract (current value of 0):

`UPDATE posts set votes=votes-1 where id='$id'`

It's having an error. Why is that so?

datatype is `int`

Comment: I dun think is an error, but a warning. Can you include the error message?

Comment: What's the numeric data type you are using with the `votes` column? Does it allow negative values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the votes column signed (so untick the unsigned checkbox).

Unsigned integer columns (which is default in most tools) can only contain positive integers. Signed integers have an extra bit for the - (so they support negative values).

Comment: where can i find checkboxes in mysql CLI client ?

Comment: No, in that case he ought to use your query. Though my explanation can help him to understand why.

Comment: how do i do that in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @user1099531 , he already explained how to do that in phpmyadmin. If you have ever used it , you would not need a grapical diagram with an interpretative dance to find that checkbox.

Comment: Might be nice to implement though, a CLI with checkboxes. So that [x] means unsigned, [ ] means signed. In phpMyAdmin, if you look at the table structure, you can see the UNSIGNED value in the attributes field. To change this, click the pencil and clear the attribute dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

`ALTER TABLE posts MODIFY votes BIGINT SIGNED DEFAULT 0;`

Something like this should help.

Answer (score 1):

first run query to make votes a signed column as suggested by **Leon**

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY votes BIGINT SIGNED;
```

Answer (score 1):

You no doubt have one of the [unsigned integral types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). These all have a minimum value of zero, so you cannot make these types negative.

Either change your code so this doesn't happen or change the datatype to a signed one.

The former can be done with something like:

```
update posts set votes = votes - 1 where id = '$id' and votes > 0
```

The latter with something like:

```
alter table post modify votes int signed
```